# requesting Metamask with "eth_requestAccounts" does not work in next.js

Tags: next.js, ethereum, solidity, web3js, metamask

This is a next.js project. I detected metamask:

```
import detectEthereumProvider from "@metamask/detect-provider";

let provider;
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  // for simplicity I am configured next.js for using top-level await
  provider = await detectEthereumProvider();
}
// Provider is detected
console.log("provider", provider);
```

This is the function to send request to metamask. It is not throwing error:

```
const connect = async () => {
    try {
      await provider.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("error in request", e);
      // location.reload();
    }
  };
```

I add click handler:

```
<Button onClick={connect}>Connect</Button>
```

Nothing is happening. so I changed the click handler to:

```
<Button
  onClick={() => {
    // this is logging.
    console.log("clicked to send request to Metamask");
    connect;
  }}
>
  Connect
</Button>
```

It is logging that I clicked it, but it is not sending the request to Metamask

Comment: In the `onClick` handler, you need to actually call the function, i.e. `await connect();`.

Answer (score 0):

First

```
      <Button
          onClick={() => {
            // this is logging.
            console.log("clicked to send request to Metamask");
            connect;
          }}
        >
          Connect
        </Button>
```

Wont work cause you need to do connect()

```
      <Button
          onClick={() => {
            // this is logging.
            console.log("clicked to send request to Metamask");
            connect(); // <===
          }}
        >
          Connect
        </Button>
```

Second connection might be working, it won't open popup if already connected.
Try doing this instead.

```
const connect = () => {
    provider.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" })
         .then(response => console.log(response)
         .catch(err => console.log(err)
  };
```

or if you want to keep it with async

```
const connect = async () => {
    try {
      const addresses = await provider.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });
      console.log(addresses)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("error in request", e);
      // location.reload();
    }
  };
```